# How can I read an Http response stream twice in C#?

Tags: c#, stream

I am trying to read an Http response stream twice via the following:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
stream = response.GetResponseStream();
RssReader reader = new RssReader(stream);
do
{
  element = reader.Read();
  if (element is RssChannel)
  {
    feed.Channels.Add((RssChannel)element);
  }
} while (element != null);

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
feed._FeedRawData = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

However when the StreamReader code executes there is no data returned because the stream has now reached the end.  I tried to reset the stream via stream.Position = 0 but this throws an exception (I think because the stream can't have its position changed manually).

Basically, I would like to parse the stream for XML and have access to the raw data (in string format).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Copy it into a new MemoryStream first. Then you can re-read the MemoryStream as many times as you like:

```
Stream responseStream = CopyAndClose(resp.GetResponseStream());
// Do something with the stream
responseStream.Position = 0;
// Do something with the stream again


private static Stream CopyAndClose(Stream inputStream)
{
    const int readSize = 256;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[readSize];
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    int count = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, readSize);
    while (count > 0)
    {
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, count);
        count = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, readSize);
    }
    ms.Position = 0;
    inputStream.Close();
    return ms;
}
```

Comment: One tiny suggestion here - I often see calls to Seek where the Position property would be simpler and more readable, e.g.

ms.Position = 0;

Just a thought for future code.

Comment: Another comment - the above doesn't end up closing the incoming stream, ever. It might be worth creating a "CopyAndClose" method which *does* close the stream, just so you could keep the simple calling syntax.

Comment: Wow, coming close to my heroes.. I'm currently reading your book, Mr. Skeet :-) What you suggested about closing (and telling with the method name) is exactly what I thought about the above code.

Comment: .net 4 and above have shorter way of copying streams: [CopyTo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/best-way-to-copy-between-two-stream-instances)

Answer (score 2):

Copying the stream to a [MemoryStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=netframework-4.0) as suggested by [Iain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/147961/2484903) is the right approach. But since 
.NET Framework 4 (released 2010) we have [Stream.CopyTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=netframework-4.0). Example from the docs:

```
// Create the streams.
MemoryStream destination = new MemoryStream();

using (FileStream source = File.Open(@"c:\temp\data.dat",
    FileMode.Open))
{

    Console.WriteLine("Source length: {0}", source.Length.ToString());

    // Copy source to destination.
    source.CopyTo(destination);
}

Console.WriteLine("Destination length: {0}", destination.Length.ToString());
```

Afterwards you can read `destination` as many times as you like:

```
// re-set to beginning and convert stream to string
destination.Position = 0;
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(destination);
string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
// re-set to beginning and read again
destination.Position = 0;
RssReader cssReader = new RssReader(destination);
```

(I have seen [Endy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147941/how-can-i-read-an-http-response-stream-twice-in-c#comment-19788214) but since it is an appropriate, current answer, it should have its own answer entry.)

Answer (score -1):

have you tried resetting the stream position?
if this does not work you can copy the stream to a MemoryStream and there you can reset the position (i.e. to 0) as often as you want.