# Copy in c# is very slow

Tags: c#, copy

I am trying to copy a lot of files using a loop and CopyTo method.
The copy is very slow. abot 10 mb per minute! (in contrast to right click in mouse and copy).

Is there any alternatives to use, which are faster?

Comment: Please read the FAQ for guidance on how to improve the phrasing of your question http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I think it is a valid question if asked properly. For example is there any fast alternate I can use rather than `CopyTo` method which is quite slow as compared to Window's `rightclick->copy->paste` in C#?

Comment: Try a while loop instead. Less overhead. :)

Comment: @Jon Whats the recipe, thts my question :P

Comment: To abstract question ,i dont think Microsoft will improve that just because it's you're problem

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help:

[File.Copy vs. Manual FileStream.Write For Copying File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246899/file-copy-vs-manual-filestream-write-for-copying-file/1247042#1247042)

It also explains why the copy function is slow.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) to buffer accordingly. As an example, something along the lines of this ought to give you an idea:

```
using (var inputStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Read),
    outputStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create))
{
    var bufferRead = -1;
    var bufferLength = 4096;
    var buffer = new byte[bufferLength];

    while ((bufferRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength)) > 0)
    {
        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferRead);
    }
}
```

Adjust the `bufferLength` accordingly. You could potentially build things around this to enhance its overall speed, but tweaking slightly should still provide a significant enough improvement.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest (and most convenient) way to copy a file is probably [`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx). Is there a reason you are not using it?