# File.Copy or Read and Write while moving a large zip file from one server to another - C#

Tags: c#

I have a situation where I need to transfer Zip file(Around 10 GB) from one server to another. Now there are two ways, one is using read stream and write stream -

```
while (inputZip.Length > nAmountWritten)
{
    buffer = reader.ReadBytes(10 * 1024 * 1024);
    bw.Write(buffer); //Binary Writer for destination
    nAmountWritten += buffer.Length;
}
```

Another is `File.Copy`.

Which way is better for transferring big files. Is it okay if I use File.Copy in such kind of scenario?

In on situation, I faced in Read And Write way is that sometime one chunk gets corrupted resulting in getting few files corrupted in Zip.

Comment: please look at this StackOverflow article. The answer is there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246899/file-copy-vs-manual-filestream-write-for-copying-file

Comment: Use File.Copy.  No need to read and write this into a stream.  You can run a batch file with Process() too.