# Write byte array to middle of an existing file in C#.NET

Tags: c#, file, random, arrays, byte

Is it possible to write (Append - No Overwrite) to an existing binary file.

I have to open a file in read write mode and then randomly write byte arrays to it at the position I specify in the file.

I am from a Java Background and I use RandomAccessFile in Java to accomplish this, but C# left me nowhere without such inbuilt functions.

Any other workaround or solution would be highly appreciated.

-Adil.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it possible to write (Append - No Overwrite) to an existing binary file.

*Appending* would be adding data at the end. That's fine. Just seek to the end of the stream after opening it in read/write mode.

It sounds like you want to *insert* data though, and that's not available. It's not something file systems tend to support. You'd need to copy the first part of the original file into a new file, write the new data, then copy the remainder of the original file.

Btw, `RandomAccessFile` doesn't support insertion either, so it's possible your Java code is broken too.

EDIT: Okay, so if you want to just overwrite, that's easy:

```
using (var stream = File.Open("file.dat", FileMode.Open))
{
    stream.Position = 100;
    // Assuming data is the data you want to write to the file
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, What I mean by appending is appending to anywhere in the file in the position I specify.
RandomAccessFile does it.
RandomAccessFile raf=new RandomAccessFile(File, "rw");
raf.seek(longPos);
raf.write(byteArray);

Comment: @user1244484: As I say, that's *inserting* data. The act of appending strictly applies to adding data at the *end* of something. And no, you can't do that in either Java or .NET. Whatever code you've got in Java using `RandomAccessFile` will be overwriting existing data.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Its overwriting. But is there any way you can overwrite to a user defined position in C#.

Comment: @user1244484: Yes - I'll edit. But it does change the whole sense of your question...

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in function for doing that. If you seek the file to a particular position (offset) by setting the position field of the stream and then write your new byte array there, this will overwrite the existing bytes after that position. You need to shift the existing bytes after the offset by the length of your intended byte array, and then write the byte array after the offset. Here is the code:

```
public static void InsertIntoFile(FileStream stream, long offset, byte[] extraBytes)
{
    if(offset < 0 || offset > stream.Length)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Offset is out of range");
    }
    const int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 512;
    int bufferSize = maxBufferSize;
    long temp = stream.Length - offset;
    if(temp <= maxBufferSize)
    {
        bufferSize = (int) temp;
    }
    byte []buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    long currentPositionToRead = fileStream.Length;
    int numberOfBytesToRead;
    while (true)
    {
        numberOfBytesToRead = bufferSize;
        temp = currentPositionToRead - offset;
        if(temp < bufferSize)
        {
            numberOfBytesToRead = (int) temp;
        }
        currentPositionToRead -= numberOfBytesToRead;
        stream.Position = currentPositionToRead; 
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, numberOfBytesToRead);
        stream.Position = currentPositionToRead + extraBytes.Length;
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, numberOfBytesToRead);
        if(temp <= bufferSize)
        {
            break; 
        }
    }
    stream.Position = offset;
    stream.Write(extraBytes, 0, extraBytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Works beautifully. Thanks for this (y)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy and quite fast solution to insert bytes in the middle of the file, just in case someone will search for inserting data and will find this question.

```
public void ExpandFile(FileStream stream, long offset, int extraBytes)
{
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033771/file-io-with-streams-best-memory-buffer-size
  const int SIZE = 4096;
  var buffer = new byte[SIZE];
  var length = stream.Length;
  // Expand file
  stream.SetLength(length + extraBytes);
  var pos = length;
  int to_read;
  while (pos > offset)
  {
    to_read = pos - SIZE >= offset ? SIZE : (int)(pos - offset);
    pos -= to_read;
    stream.Position = pos;
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, to_read);
    stream.Position = pos + extraBytes;
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, to_read);
  }
```

Need to be checked, though...