# C# : FTP upload buffer size

Tags: c#, upload, ftp, io, buffer

I have go that FTP Upload function , but there is something that i want to ask about
It is the Buffer size , i set it to 20KB what does it mean and would it make difference if i increased/decreased it ?

```
    private void Upload(string filename)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename);

        FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://" + textBox1.Text + "/" + Path.GetFileName(filename));
        ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
        ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        ftp.UseBinary = true;
        ftp.KeepAlive = false;
        ftp.ContentLength = fi.Length;

        // The buffer size is set to 20kb
        int buffLength = 20480;
        byte[] buff = new byte[buffLength];
        int contentLen;

        //int totalReadBytesCount = 0;

        FileStream fs = fi.OpenRead();

        try
        {
            // Stream to which the file to be upload is written
            Stream strm = ftp.GetRequestStream();

            // Read from the file stream 2kb at a time
            contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);

            // Till Stream content ends
            while (contentLen != 0)
            {
                // Write Content from the file stream to the 
                // FTP Upload Stream
                strm.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
                contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
            }

            // Close the file stream and the Request Stream
            strm.Close();
            fs.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Upload Error");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For FTP on desktop systems block size of about 256Kb produced the best performance in our tests. Small buffer sizes decrease speed of transfer significantly. I recommend that you do some measurements yourself, but 20Kb is definitely too little for a buffer.

Comment: I cannot believe what a difference that made for my SFTP applications. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

> Files are already buffered by the file system cache.  You should use
>   something  lower than 20KB.  4 KB is a traditional choice and I really
>   wouldn't go lower than 4 KB.  Don't go below a kilobyte, more than 16
>   KB is a waste of memory and unfriendly to the CPU's L1 cache
>   (typically 16 or 32 KB of data).

Hans (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3034155)

**`Use 4 KB (AKA 4096 b)`**

In .Net 4.5 they increased the default value to 81920 bytes and using the .Net Reflector shows the _DefaultCopyBufferSize has a value of 0x14000 (81920b, or 80K). However, this is for copying from stream to stream, not buffering data. The BufferedStream Class has a _DefaultBufferSize of 0x1000 (4096b or 4k).

Comment: Could you explain the reason why a buffer below 20KB should be chosen?  It makes the transfer very slow!

Comment: Even microsoft defaults it to 4KB.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream(v=vs.110).aspx - If use use the wrapped up MS `FtpPutFile()` you in fact would be using a buffer size of 4KB.  Not sure why my answer would be wrong (and you would fell the need to downvote) if it's something that is built into the framework ...

Comment: Also added the source of my answer.  A lot of others seem to agree with me on that answer.  - As a side note I also send small files as well (40KB or so) and that work VERY well for me.  If you have larger files your going to want to use a larger buffer for best performance I would think.

Comment: No problem @Toshi. ;)