# Why memory size of ByteArray is always 1024

Tags: arrays, c#-4.0, byte

I am looking into web examples of Byte Array. Now from below statement i understand that I am creating a Byte Array which can stone 1024 values by why 1024 is always used in any of byte array example i found on internet?

byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[1024];

Value "1024" can be anything depending upon my requirements, Right?

Comment: It is a nice round number when you count with two fingers like computers do, 1024 == Math.Pow(2, 10).  Programmers say "one kilobyte".  256 and 4096 are other common values.  If this is a buffer to read data from a file or a network socket then you [typically prefer 4096](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3034155/17034).

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for it.