# async await web api file io

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-4.5

I'm using the following async code in a web api controller to process an XML file.  Everything works as expected, however is this the correct use of the async/await approach.  I'm basically extracting all images from the XML file and then saving them to disk.  I wanted to try an minimise the impact of file io.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFile()
{
    await Task.WhenAll(this.ProcessProofOfPressenceImages(address, images, surveyReference), this.ProcessSketchImages(propertyPlans, images, surveyReference), this.ProcessExteriorImages(exteriorSketch, images, surveyReference));
    //db code
}

private async Task ProcessProofOfPressenceImages(Dictionary<object, object> container, List<Dictionary<string, string>> images, string surveyReference)
{
    if(images != null)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(this.ProcessImagesHelper(container, images, surveyReference, "propertyImage"));
    }
}

private async Task ProcessSketchImages(Dictionary<object, object> container, List<Dictionary<string, string>> images, string surveyReference)
{
    if(images != null)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(this.ProcessImagesHelper(container, images, surveyReference, "sketchPlanImage"), this.ProcessImagesHelper(container, images, surveyReference, "sketchFrontImage"), this.ProcessImagesHelper(container, images, surveyReference, "sketchRearImage"), this.ProcessImagesHelper(container, images, surveyReference, "sketchLeftSideImage"), this.ProcessImagesHelper(container, images, surveyReference, "sketchRightSideImage"));
    }
}

private async Task ProcessExteriorImages(Dictionary<object, object> container, List<Dictionary<string, string>> images, string surveyReference)
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    if(images != null)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(this.ProcessImagesHelper(container, images, surveyReference, "image1"), this.ProcessImagesHelper(container, images, surveyReference, "image2"), this.ProcessImagesHelper(container, images, surveyReference, "image3"), this.ProcessImagesHelper(container, images, surveyReference, "image4"), this.ProcessImagesHelper(container, images, surveyReference, "image5"), this.ProcessImagesHelper(container, images, surveyReference, "image6"));
    }
}

private async Task ProcessImagesHelper(Dictionary<object, object> container, List<Dictionary<string, string>> images, string surveyReference, string image)
{
    if(container.ContainsKey(image) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(container[image].ToString()))
    {
        using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream((byte[])container[image]))
        {
            string url = String.Format(@"{0}{1}{2}_{3}.jpg", EcoConfiguration.Instance.RootUrl, EcoConfiguration.Instance.SurveyImageRootUrl, surveyReference, image.SplitOnCapital("_"));

            using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(url, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> imageDetails = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                imageDetails.Add("TypeId", ((int)SurveyImageType.Exterior).ToString());
                imageDetails.Add("ImageUrl", url);
                if(container.ContainsKey(image + "Description"))
                {
                    imageDetails.Add("Description", container[image + "Description"].ToSafeString());
                }
                images.Add(imageDetails);
                await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any comments/suggestions would be very welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tricky thing about file streams is that you need to pass `isAsync: true` or `FileOptions.Asynchronous` to the constructor/factory method to get a truly asynchronous stream. If you don't do this, then the underlying file stream is actually blocking and the asynchronous methods just use the thread pool to *fake* asynchronous operations.

The other thing that stands out to me in your code is that you've got some unnecessary use of `async`. `async` should be used only when you *need* it. E.g., this method:

```
private async Task ProcessProofOfPressenceImages(Dictionary<object, object> container, List<Dictionary<string, string>> images, string surveyReference)
{
  if(images != null)
  {
    await Task.WhenAll(this.ProcessImagesHelper(container, images, surveyReference, "propertyImage"));
  }
}
```

could be written as:

```
private Task ProcessProofOfPressenceImages(Dictionary<object, object> container, List<Dictionary<string, string>> images, string surveyReference)
{
  if(images != null)
  {
    return Task.WhenAll(this.ProcessImagesHelper(container, images, surveyReference, "propertyImage"));
  }

  return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

which saves you an unnecessary state machine. The same advice would apply to `ProcessSketchImages` and `ProcessExteriorImages`.

Regarding `ProcessImagesHelper`, it looks pretty good, though I'm not sure why you need the `MemoryStream`. It would be just as easy to (asynchronously) write the byte array out to disk.

If you're interested in `async` performance tips, [Stephen Toub has an excellent video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T).

Comment: Stephen, thanks for the reply and advice - very much appreciated - all of the async methods didn't feel right!  I've changed the code as suggested and removed the need for the MemoryStream and set the isAsync parameter to true.  I used another article (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862982/c-sharp-filestream-optimal-buffer-size-for-writing-large-files) to determine an optimal buffer size for the FileStream.