# Is there any reason that default buffer sizes are 4096?

Tags: c#, buffer, filestream, streamwriter, bufferstrategy

I often see 4096 used as a default buffer size all over the place. Is there any reason why 4096 was selected as opposed to another value?

Comment: Jon Skeet picked that number.

Comment: I believe it has something to do with memory page sizes.

Comment: @michael: Jon Skeet *invented* that number.  Prior to his writing buffer code, the universe skipped from 4095 to 4097.  (Couldn't resist.  It's an old meme, but a fun one.)

Comment: It's the size of a page.

Comment: The answer is 42 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy

Comment: @DavidHeffernan except if is the "page" is an A4 page, 210mm x 297mm

Comment: It ***is*** a common [page size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)), 4*1024 or 4K.

Answer (score 5):

It is realy depending on your problem but a general compromise solution for the problem is 4KB. 
A good description for this choice you will find it under the below listed links:

[File I/O with streams - best memory buffer size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033771/file-io-with-streams-best-memory-buffer-size)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ed3c6dea-400e-489c-9a86-b43b3a78cc1c/quick-question-about-filestream-buffering?forum=csharpgeneral

[C# FileStream : Optimal buffer size for writing large files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862982/c-sharp-filestream-optimal-buffer-size-for-writing-large-files)