# vb.net How to read a small part of a very large file not using memory?

Tags: vb.net, file, memory

I use a console app to work on large files. I use

```
IO.File.ReadAllBytes(OpenFileDlg.FileName)
```

but it loads all the large file on memory and stops when the memory is full , without reading it completely.
I want to split the large file or read a part of it, "without loading all the file on memory, so it would work on small RAM"

Comment: Do you know at what offset you need to begin to read? If so, use a Stream and [`Seek()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.seek) that offset.

Comment: no, I try to open large files not texts, there may be an HD video, so i don't have an offset

Comment: Yes, well, it's the opposite. You don't have an offset if it's a text file, usually. Maybe you're looking for a string. If it's a - let's call it *binary* - file, then you can specify an offset. Are you saying that you don't know where to start to read? What is that you're actually trying to do with these files?

Comment: converting the large file into hex then saving it. it works if the file is about 150mb or less only.

Comment: What does *converting the large file into hex* mean? Are you saying that you want to convert your files to a Base64 string? Why?

Comment: I already convert files from binary into Hex.
but it works on memory, so this can not work on large files.

Comment: *convert files from binary into Hex* doesn't mean anything. Are you converting byte arrays to a string representation? What's the use of it? Are you storing these things in a database? Something else?

Comment: yes i convert byte arrays to a string. then i save this string in a file. the problem is:  `IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename)` It reads all the file on memory and this cannot work on large files in my small ram. so i want a way to split the file first without loading it on ram.

Comment: All right, you're converting byte arrays to strings. Why? What's the reason and the destination of this operation (assume that, since I'm asking, it's something that counts)? Also, what kind of strings? Are those Base64 strings or something else (it also counts)? What will happen to these strings (still counts)?

Comment: for encryption on a byte level

Comment: To encrypt files, you write the content to a [CryptoStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream) with a standard provider, AES (RijndaelManaged) etc. In its simpler form, it's a sequential write to a Stream. No need to convert to string or to load into memory anything.

Comment: my app already encrypts files

Comment: Do you mean that you're already using a CryptoStream to generate encrypted files? So, what is your question about?

Comment: no. i made something like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FileStream` to read in chunks of 4096 bytes then encrypt them (or do any necessary processing) and then write them to the new file stream, since it's streaming in/out it won't hog up all the memory trying to read/write everything at once, simple example:

```
Dim bytesRead As Integer
Dim buffer(4096) As Byte 'Default buffer size is 4096
Using inFile As New IO.FileStream("C:\\Temp\\inFile.bin", FileMode.Open)
    Using outFile As New IO.FileStream("C:\\Temp\\outFile.bin", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
        Do
            bytesRead = inFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            If bytesRead > 0 Then
                ' Do encryption or any necessary processing of the bytes
                outFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
            End If
        Loop While bytesRead > 0
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: ok, i tried it. It is a real life saver. but with one small problem. After completion, It added one full megabyte to a 33 mb file. when i tried it on a small 200 byte text file, It added 4 kb to it and had 3860 space at the end of the file . I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: @AreegGhonaim had a typo in there, it should be `outFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)` check the edit

Comment: @AreegGhonaim Welcome to SO, please read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: hey can i use memory stream? i want this code to do that buffer depending on the available physical memory ,so that it would work faster if there r more rams?

Comment: `FileStream` is already in memory and uses 4kb as the default buffer size, there's an overloaded constructor that allows to specify how large the buffer should be, but it's hard to tell if you'll see any benefits from increasing the buffer size, need to benchmark to determine the actual performance, please see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862982/c-sharp-filestream-optimal-buffer-size-for-writing-large-files