# How to use Stream.CopyTo on .NET Framework 3.5?

Tags: c#

I found upload code and this code contains the `Stream.CopyTo` method.

Example:

```
  file.Stream.CopyTo(requestStream); // .NET Framework 4.0
```

How can I copy "file.Stream" to "requestStream"?

Comment: In .NET version prior to 4.0 you must write your own method to copy the stream: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/best-way-to-copy-between-two-stream-instances-c

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can't, basically. It's only implemented in .NET 4. You can write a similar method yourself though... and even make it an extension method:

```
// Only useful before .NET 4
public static void CopyTo(this Stream input, Stream output)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024]; // Fairly arbitrary size
    int bytesRead;

    while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

Comment: For a moment there I thought there was some awesome C# extension method feature I hadn't seen before!

Comment: Yea you have to remove it :) Thx again

Comment: Async stream copy method can be found in .NET 4.5 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copytoasync.aspx
Async copy implementation for .NET 4.0 and less: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540658/net-asynchronous-stream-read-write

Comment: For `MemoryStream`, you will want to add `input.Position = 0` otherwise

Comment: @JonSkeet I used your example, how the heck do i stop the infinite read in while() if the Stream is a NetworkStream without forcing it out with a timeout as workaround. After sending all data this code remains stuck in Read mode, tried to use checks bytes sent or anything but it won't even reach the checks, if's or other stuff. The while condition remains true for the last read which is stuck on infinite read

Comment: @RaresAndrei: Basically you shouldn't read something that reads "until the end of the stream" with a stream that doesn't have an end. You should think about what condition you want to check for to see whether or not you've reached a suitable stopping point - that will depend on your context.