# AES cryptography in vb6 and c#

Tags: c#, vb6, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

I need a .NET *(C# ideally)* algorithm that will produce the same results as a `vb6` one I made to encrypt and `decrypt` binary files. I've been trying to hunt down code for a week now and have had little success.

I started with [How to encrypt a string in VB6 decrypt VB.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;821762) but it was only a half solution and it used `RC2` rather than `AES`. After some fiddling I got my `vb6` code to work in `AES` but I cannot find a way to get `c#` to produce the same results. I think it has to do with the way I'm making my `Key` and `IV`. I've been going over [Cryptographic Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93bskf9z.aspx) my attempts can be broken into two basic types. One where I have tried `PasswordDeriveBytes.CryptDeriveKey` and trying to make it work with `aes`. No success at all. And Tries where I tried to mimic it's behavior. Bellow I will post my `vb6` code and my closest `c#` attempt. I can't say with 100% certainty that the `vb6` is perfect so if changes need to be made there I'm open to it. I know there is a way to use p invoke and I know there is a way to make `.net dll` to be called from my `vb apps`. I would prefer not to go that way.

VB6 Function

```
Public Function Crypt_File(PathToSourceFile As String, PathToDestFile As String, Password As String, HowTo As CryptMethod) As Boolean
Const FName As String = "mdlCryptography.Encrypt_file"
Dim CryptoContext As Long
Dim strProvider As String
Dim HashHnd As Long
Dim CrypKey As Long
Dim Step As Integer
Dim CryptBuff As String
Dim InFileNum As Long, OutFileNum As Long
Dim BytesRemaining As Long, CurrentBufferSize  As Long
Dim MAX_BUFFER_SIZE As Long
Dim DoCryptFinalise As Long
Dim Buff As String
On Error GoTo Trap:
    Step = 10
    Crypt_File = False
    If PathToSourceFile = PathToDestFile Then '
        Err.Raise 334, FName, "Sourse and Dest Path are the same"
    End If
    MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = (2 ^ 20) * 100 '100 MB
    Buff = vbNullChar
    strProvider = MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV_A & vbNullChar
    If Not CBool(CryptAcquireContext(CryptoContext, ByVal Buff, ByVal strProvider, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)) Then
        Err.Raise 33410, FName, "Unable to Acquire Context: " & MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV_A
    End If

    If Not CBool(CryptCreateHash(CryptoContext, CALG_SHA_256, ByVal 0&, ByVal 0&, HashHnd)) Then
        Err.Raise 33420, FName, "Unable to Create a hash object. " & MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV_A
    End If

    If Not CBool(CryptHashData(HashHnd, Password, Len(Password), ByVal 0&)) Then
        Err.Raise 33430, FName, "Unable to Hash password. "
    End If

    If Not CBool(CryptDeriveKey(CryptoContext, CALG_AES_256, HashHnd, ByVal CRYPT_NO_SALT, CrypKey)) Then
        Err.Raise 33440, FName, "Unable to Derive Key. "
    End If
    'Clear HashHnd
    If HashHnd <> 0 Then
        Call CryptDestroyHash(HashHnd)
    End If
    HashHnd = 0

    'Prep Data For encryption
    DoCryptFinalise = 0
    InFileNum = FreeFile
    Step = 20
    Open PathToSourceFile For Binary Access Read As #InFileNum
    If LenB(Dir$(PathToDestFile)) > 0 Then
        Kill PathToDestFile
    End If
    OutFileNum = FreeFile
    Step = 25
    Open PathToDestFile For Binary Access Write As #OutFileNum

    BytesRemaining = LOF(InFileNum)
    'Loop through File Chunks
    Do While BytesRemaining > 0

        If BytesRemaining >= MAX_BUFFER_SIZE Then
            CurrentBufferSize = MAX_BUFFER_SIZE
        Else
            CurrentBufferSize = BytesRemaining
            DoCryptFinalise = 1
        End If

        Buff = String$(CurrentBufferSize, vbNullChar)
        Get #InFileNum, , Buff
            If HowTo = CryptMethod.Encrypt Then
                CryptBuff = EncryptBuffer(CrypKey, DoCryptFinalise, Buff)
            Else
                CryptBuff = DecryptBuffer(CrypKey, DoCryptFinalise, Buff)
            End If
        Put #OutFileNum, , CryptBuff

        BytesRemaining = BytesRemaining - CurrentBufferSize
    Loop
    Close #InFileNum
    Close #OutFileNum
    Crypt_File = True

GoTo Fin
Trap:
    Crypt_File = False
    If Step = 20 Then
        Close #InFileNum
    End If
    If Step = 25 Then
        Close #InFileNum
        Close #OutFileNum
    End If
    Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.source, Err.Description
Fin:

    If CrypKey <> 0 Then
        Call CryptDestroyKey(CrypKey)
    End If
    If HashHnd <> 0 Then
        Call CryptDestroyHash(HashHnd)
    End If
End Function

Private Function EncryptBuffer(CrypKey As Long, DoCryptFinalise As Long, Buff As String) As String
Dim EncDataLength As Long, EnctBuffLen As Long
Dim CryptBuff As String

    EncDataLength = Len(Buff)
    EnctBuffLen = EncDataLength + AES_BLOCK_SIZE
    CryptBuff = String$(EnctBuffLen, vbNullChar)
    LSet CryptBuff = Buff
    If Not CBool(CryptEncrypt(CrypKey, ByVal 0&, ByVal DoCryptFinalise, ByVal 0&, CryptBuff, EncDataLength, EnctBuffLen)) Then
'        Close #InFileNum
'        Close #OutFileNum
        Err.Raise 33450, "mdlCryptography.EncryptBuffer", "Encryption Error"
    End If
    EncryptBuffer = Left$(CryptBuff, EncDataLength)
End Function


Private Function DecryptBuffer(CrypKey As Long, DoCryptFinalise As Long, Buff As String) As String
Dim EncDataLength As Long
Dim CryptBuff As String

    EncDataLength = Len(Buff)
    CryptBuff = String$(EncDataLength, vbNullChar)
    LSet CryptBuff = Buff
    If Not CBool(CryptDecrypt(CrypKey, ByVal 0&, ByVal DoCryptFinalise, ByVal 0&, CryptBuff, EncDataLength)) Then
'        Close #InFileNum
'        Close #OutFileNum
        Err.Raise 33450, "mdlCryptography.DecryptBuffer", "Decryption Error"
    End If
    DecryptBuffer = Left$(CryptBuff, EncDataLength)
End Function
```

c# It's very much unrefined

```
private void Crypt(bool DoEn)
{
    int Rfc2898KeygenIterations = 100;
    int AesKeySizeInBits = 128;
    byte[] rawPlaintext ;//= System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("This is all clear now!");
    byte[] cipherText = null;
    byte[] plainText = null;

    using (Aes aes = new AesManaged())
    {

        int KeyStrengthInBytes = aes.KeySize / 8;

        SHA256 MySHA = new SHA256Cng();
        MySHA.Initialize();
        plainText = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtPassword.Text);
        aes.Key = MySHA.ComputeHash(plainText );
        aes.IV =  Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0000000000000000");
        if (DoEn)
        {
            //using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(txtOut.Text,FileMode.CreateNew ))
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    //using (StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(txtIn.Text))
                    //{
                    //    rawPlaintext = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myFile.ReadToEnd());
                        rawPlaintext = File.ReadAllBytes(txtIn.Text);
                        cs.Write(rawPlaintext, 0, rawPlaintext.Length);

                    //}
                }
                cipherText = ms.ToArray();
                File.WriteAllBytes(txtOut.Text, cipherText);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(txtIn.Text, FileMode.CreateNew))
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    //using (StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(txtOut.Text))
                    //{
                        //string s = myFile.r.ReadToEnd();
                        rawPlaintext = File.ReadAllBytes(txtOut.Text); //System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
                        //cipherText = new int[rawPlaintext.Length];
                        cs.Write(rawPlaintext, 0, rawPlaintext.Length);
                        //cs.Write(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
                    //}
                }
                cipherText = ms.ToArray();
                File.WriteAllBytes(txtIn.Text, cipherText);
            }
        }
    }
    //string s = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(plainText);
    //Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: msdn has a simple sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx

Comment: Awful lot of code you want us to read.

Comment: Just in case anyone else finds this useful, the vb code hasn't changed. I used [@HABO's post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237324/encrypting-decrypting-large-files-net) and [@Jon Skeet's post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730863/how-to-use-stream-copyto-on-framework-3-5) to make my c# work with large files.

Comment: Found another Gotcha On Pre vista OS. If you use SHA256 you need to use "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" However on xp that provider does not exist. You need to use "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider (Prototype)" and be up to SP3. [More Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/01/23/sha-2-support-on-windows-xp.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to me that in the VB6 sample you are specifying CRYPT_NO_SALT which I believe results in a no initialization vector being used. Presumably this is all zeroes but I'm not sure.

However in the C# code you are getting bytes for the ASCII text "0000000000000000" which is not the same as a byte array of the number zero { 0, 0, 0, 0, ... 0 } as the character '0' is equal to the number 48 in ASCII (see: http://www.asciitable.com/). I think this is likely to be the source of your problems.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your answer @Lummo. +1 for answering first.

Comment: Well that's a little embarrassing. I guess sometimes it's hard to see the simple errors. Thanks a lot! It was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your vector here will produce a different result than what you might expect:

```
aes.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0000000000000000");
```

This will return a byte array consisting of 48's, not 0's.

You can simply initialize a byte array instead like this:

```
aes.IV = new byte() {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

Comment: Thanks for the syntax. I'm not a c# programmer and it saved me having to look it up. Appreciated!