# Retrieving a file collection and saving them in a local directory

Tags: c#, sharepoint, filestream

I am having issues saving a Sharepoint filecollection of picture to a local directory.  I am very new with Sharepoint 2016 and I am having issues resolving this issue.  Seems like when I run this code it makes a first pass to give me the first image of my file collection.  However when I look into the intended directory the image is 0 bytes(Just an empty file).  After it stays running for a little while it throws the following exception error.

> Error:
>   Additional information: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

```
public static void ImageRetrival(DHG.OneDrive.Helpers.OneDriveHelper oneDrive, string user)
{
    try
    {
        var wb = userContext.Web;
        userContext.Load(wb);
        var files = oneDrive.GetOneDriveFilesByFolderName(user);
        var test = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(userContext, wb.ServerRelativeUrl);
        FileStream fs = null;

        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var fileName = file.Name.ToString();
                string path = @"C:\Top-Level\" + fileName;
                fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                test.Stream.CopyTo(fs);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: look at @JonSkeets example here it looks to be a lot cleaner in my opinion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730863/how-to-use-stream-copyto-on-net-framework-3-5

Comment: @Method man, I got it to work it was more logical sequence rather then code.  Please take a look at the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out, logic was wrong I had the following line outside my for each loops which was making it empty when I was calling it back in for each code.  This was the reason my file was coming up as 0 Bytes.

Corrected Code

```
    public static void ImageRetrival(PHG.OneDrive.Helpers.OneDriveHelper oneDrive, string user)
    {

        try
        {
            var wb = userContext.Web;
            userContext.Load(wb);
            var files = oneDrive.GetOneDriveFilesByFolderName(user);

            if (files != null)
            {

                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    // has to be inside my foreach loop referencing file in files which represents a sharepoint filecollection 
                    var fileinfo  = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(userContext, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
                    var fileName = file.Name.ToString();
                    string path = @"C:\Top-Level\" + fileName;
                    using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        fileinfo.Stream.CopyTo(fs);
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

    }
```