# Can starting multiple asyncronous read/write operations on the same Stream corrupt the data?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, io, concurrent-programming

I'm using asynchronous I/O because it does not block the calling thread and does the threading stuff behind the scenes. If I invoke multiple async operations like BeginWrite()'s on the same Stream, should I need to worry about that data buffer contents are mixed together?

Let's assume I want to send 3 buffers:

```
Buffer1: 1111111111
Buffer2: 2222222222
Buffer3: 3333333333
```

I don't mind if the buffers are sent in incorrect order, so

```
333333333311111111112222222222
```

is ok, but is it possible that buffer contents are got completely mixed together?

```
122213121212122333313111223333
```

PS: I'm 100% sure that someone already asked this in some form...

Comment: Does it not matter in which order the 3 buffers are sent? What if the data is sent as 222233331111, ie. no interleaving but "incorrect" order?

Comment: Yup, similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540658/net-asynchronous-stream-read-write

Comment: I guess you shouldn't do that. MSND states about the **Stream** object - Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: Be sure to read http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;156932, particularly the part that says, "Another reason that I/O operations are completed synchronously is the operations themselves. On Windows NT, any write operation to a file that extends its length will be synchronous."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the implementation of the Stream. For instance sockets support multiple overlapped requests both for read and for write, and so does the file API. They guarantee consistency of each operation (no interleaving content) and also order of operations: for instance for socket reads the bytes received will be placed in the buffers posted in the order posted. If these guarantees would not be provided it would impossible to write high performance network application, as overlapping Sends are *desired* but overlapping Receives are actually **required** for high performance network IO. This behavior is described in many articles, including good ole' [Windows Sockets 2.0: Write Scalable Winsock Apps Using Completion Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302334.aspx) and is documented on MSDN [Overlapped Input/Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Both send and receive operations can
>   be overlapped. The receive functions
>   may be invoked multiple times to post
>   receive buffers in preparation for
>   incoming data, and the send functions
>   may be invoked multiple times to queue
>   up multiple buffers to be sent. Note
>   that while a series of overlapped send
>   buffers will be sent in the order
>   supplied, the corresponding completion
>   indications may occur in a different
>   order. Likewise, on the receiving
>   side, buffers will be filled in the
>   order they are supplied, but
>   completion indications may occur in a
>   different order.

Not surprisingly, the same guarantees carry over to the managed side of the world, eg. the [`NetworkStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread.aspx) class:

> Read and write operations can be
>   performed simultaneously on an
>   instance of the NetworkStream class
>   without the need for synchronization.
>   As long as there is one unique thread
>   for the write operations and one
>   unique thread for the read operations,
>   there will be no cross-interference
>   between read and write threads and no
>   synchronization is required.

That being said, throwing randomly async reads and writes on a Stream will result in chaos pretty quickly. Applications need to carefully orchestrate the order in which threads submit the operations so that the order is deterministic. Usually this means keeping accounting in a (synchronized) list with special care to do the async operation invocation *while* holding the synchronization lock.

One final note is that *all* these async APIs make a special note in calling out that the order of *completion* is not guaranteed to match the order of submission.

Comment: So basically if I lock the NetworkStream while calling BeginWrite I won't have problems and concurrent running async operations won't conflict with each other.

Answer (score 0):

No, file streams do not support multiple concurrent IOs. The Windows file system does not handle that well. It will almost certainly throw an exception.

Edit:

[Synchronization and Overlapped Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686358%28VS.85%29.aspx) seems to indicate that the file system will correctly handle multiple overlapped IO requests. My bad.

Do not, however, try to do concurrent *synchronous* writes on a `FileStream`. *That* throws an exception.

Comment: -1 There is ample documentation on MSDN that proves the contrary

Comment: @Remus: please provide a link.

Comment: There are several links in my response

Comment: @Remus: All of which mention Windows Sockets, not the file API. I'll go look.