# Is Stream.Copy piped?

Tags: c#, tcp, stream

Suppose I am writing a tcp proxy code. 
I am reading from the incoming stream and writing to the output stream. 
I know that Stream.Copy uses a buffer, but my question is: 
Does the Stream.Copy method writes to the output stream while fetching the next chunk from the input stream or it a loop like "read chunk from input, write chunk to ouput, read chunk from input, etc" ?

Comment: Interesting question; I don't actually know without checking. Of course, it should be noted that doing this would require 2 separate buffers (or two separate portions of a single buffer).

Comment: Yes, It's pretty obvious that a double buffer is needed. But i'm not sure that the Stream.Copy function is that smart.

Comment: It should be noted that if it used a pipe it would then be doing two stream copies, which would then involve a further two pipes, which ...

Answer (score 6):

Here's the implementation of `CopyTo` in .NET 4.5:

```
private void InternalCopyTo(Stream destination, int bufferSize)
{
    int num;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    while ((num = this.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        destination.Write(buffer, 0, num);
    }
}
```

So as you can see, it reads from the source, *then* writes to the destination. This could probably be improved ;)

---

*EDIT:* here's a possible implementation of a piped version:

```
public static void CopyToPiped(this Stream source, Stream destination, int bufferSize = 0x14000)
{
    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    byte[] writeBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int bytesRead = source.Read(readBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        Swap(ref readBuffer, ref writeBuffer);
        var iar = destination.BeginWrite(writeBuffer, 0, bytesRead, null, null);
        bytesRead = source.Read(readBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        destination.EndWrite(iar);
    }
}

static void Swap<T>(ref T x, ref T y)
{
    T tmp = x;
    x = y;
    y = tmp;
}
```

Basically, it reads a chunk synchronously, starts to copy it to the destination asynchronously, then read the next chunk and waits for the write to complete.

I ran a few performance tests:

- using `MemoryStream`s, I didn't expect a significant improvement, since it doesn't use IO completion ports (AFAIK); and indeed, the performance is almost identical
- using files on different drives, I expected the piped version to perform better, but it doesn't... it's actually slightly slower (by 5 to 10%)

So it apparently doesn't bring any benefit, which is probably the reason why it isn't implemented this way...

Comment: I believe the buffer size plays an important role when using files.

Comment: @IsraelLot, yes, probably. The default buffer size I used is the same as in the default Stream.Copy implementation.

Comment: The ideal solution would be to alternate between two buffers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4139427/648265

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, your edit in my code was incorrect, it caused an empty buffer to be written to the output stream. I rolled it back. Please don't make significant edits to other people's code, unless it's just to fix an obvious syntax error or typo.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: Writing 0 bytes should be a no-op - what's wrong with that?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: I just didn't like the reference juggling. The C-style array index technique looks more streamlined.

Answer (score 2):

According to Reflector it does not. Such behavior better be documented because it would introduce concurrency. This is never safe to do in general. So the API design to not "pipe" is sound.

So this is not just a question of `Stream.Copy` being more or less smart. Copying in a concurrent way is not an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

Stream.Copy is synchronous operation. I don't think it is reasonable to expect it to use asynchronous read/write to make simultaneous read and write.

I would expect asynchrounous version (like [RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241747.aspx)) to use simultaneous read and write.

Note: using multiple threads during copy would be unwelcome behavior, but using asynchronous read and write to run them at the same time is ok.

Comment: Asynchonous does not imply concurrent. Going concurrent with proper documentation and being very explicit about it would be very dangerous. Almost nothing is thread-safe by default.

Comment: @usr, not sure what your comment is about... maybe confusing usage of "parallel"? See edit (parallel -> simultaneous).

Comment: Sry, my comment was unclear. Referring to this: "I would expect asynchrounous version ... to ... simultaneous read and write.": RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync can't do this simultaneously because that would potentially introduce race conditions in user/framework code. Both read and write could access a shared variable or such.

Comment: @usr What race conditions? I would be very surprised if a stream the supports async read/write operations (BeginXXX/EndXXX pair of XXXAsync for 4.5) would explicitly impement them to have race conditions. Now for user's code - asynchronous operation will call back on the same thread as they were started, no concurrency issues here. The only immediate problem I can see if the same buffer is used for desitnation or Read and source of Write but it is only issue if whoever calls asynchronos methods explicitly shares it...

Comment: the read and write calls might run on a custom stream implementation. They might for example increment a "static int readWriteCount" variable. If called concurrently a race exists. Again: Asynchrony does not imply parallelism. For that reason the async read and write calls must not be thread-safe internally. They might expect to run on one thread at a time (although on different threads over time).

Comment: @usr, I guess we both arguing for exactly the same thing - there is no word that describes "2 operations run *at the same time* on the same thread" (as in case of starting BeginRead and BeginWrite operations on after each other in the code).  Or I'm missing something again?

Answer (score -1):

Writing to the output stream is impossible (when using one buffer) while fetching next chunk because fetching the next chunk can overwrite the buffer while its being used for output.
You can say use double buffering but its pretty much the same as using a double sized buffer.

Comment: Since (as you yourself note) we can use a separate buffer (or fragment of buffer), it is clearly not "impossible".