# Download file to client asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, download

I'm having a hard time getting something done.

I am building an mailclient using asp.net MVC 4.

I am at the point that i have to download an image related to a message ( NOT an attachment ) to the client browser.

Now i have this setup :

Client browser -> Controller/backend -> Mail server

to clarify : i have a client request containing the content ID of the image, the right mailbox, message etc. With that information i can download the image from the Mail server and upload it to the client.
Now comes the hard part: I want to do this asynchronous. I want to be able to download a chunk of 512 KB from the mailserver, decode that part, and send it to the client.. fetch - decode - send.. So long that the browser got all the data of the image.

I just dont want to first download ALL the data first to the server and then create a new memorystream with all that data and return that as a fileresult. I am just too afraid of getting too large files in my memory and block other processes etc.

I am planning to use this method too of uploading real attachments ( which could be 100's of MBs ). So i am gonna need that method later on.

Now i just have no idea how to achieve this, because i have a connection to the mail server, and i have a connection to the client. and i have to pass data to a new stream or something to get this done..

Can someone please help me?

Edit: to clarify: no i cannot refer to the file on the mail server. i HAVE to download the file to the server through sockets.

Edit2: could http chuncked be the solution? If yes, could you give me a small example?

Comment: What kind of client browsers do you need to support? Do they support websockets? Essentially you just want your mailserver to proxy a stream, as far as I can tell, and how difficult this will be depends in part on what your browser support requirements are.

Comment: I can not support any websocket ( needs to be compatible with IE 8 , IE 9 ). can i somehow pass a stream and tell the controller/response to read an X amount of chars out of it ? becouse that would solve everything

Comment: Either that or just have your server function as a reverse proxy (so when the client requests a URL, stream back the data in one go without manually chunking or resorting to sockets). Unfortunately I don't know enough about ASP.NET to be able to help any further with that.

Comment: Could u give me an example on how to stream in one go ? Becouse that sounds like the solution. I cna do then this:
Streamreader.read(data.amountofbytes) and pass that to a new stream and return that stream as new file?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to copy data from one stream (the tcp connection to the mail server) to another (the http connection to the browser), right?  If you want to scale, you'll need to use non-blocking IO as described in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337900.aspx).  So you'll want to call the code in that article from an IHttpAsyncHandler implementation.  You'll end up with something like this:

```
class MyHandler : IHttpAsyncHandler
{
    public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
    {
        Stream src = null; // remote data source
        Stream dst = context.Response.OutputStream;

        // set content type, etc

        var res = new MyResult();

        AsynchCopy(src, dst, () =>
            {
                ((ManualResetEvent)res.AsyncWaitHandle).Set();
                cb(res);
                src.Close();
                dst.Flush();
            });

        return res;
    }

    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    class MyResult : IAsyncResult
    {
        public MyResult()
        {
            AsyncWaitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        }

        public object AsyncState
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public bool CompletedSynchronously
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public bool IsCompleted
        {
            get { return AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(0); }
        }
    }

    public static void AsynchCopy(Stream src, Stream dst, Action done)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2560];
        AsyncCallback readCallback = null, writeCallback = null;

        readCallback = (readResult) =>
        {
            int read = src.EndRead(readResult);
            if (read > 0)
            {
                dst.BeginWrite(buffer, 0, read, writeCallback, null);
            }
            else
            {
                done();
            }
        };

        writeCallback = (writeResult) =>
        {
            dst.EndWrite(writeResult);
            src.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, readCallback, null);
        };

        src.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, readCallback, null);
    }
}
```

The above code is untested and doesn't contain error handling, but it should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your idea and your sample code! I'm going to give it a try as soon as i am able to get to it! 
I think it is going to be hard to implement in our architecture, but the asynchronous part will save me i think. I'll get back to it asap!