# using how much buffer size for Stream.CopyToAsync is faster and optimized?

Tags: c#, optimization

I am writing a stream to a file by

```
stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream, [bufferSize])
```

I want to know how much buffer size is better to use for a faster operation?

files are from 100KB to 1 or 2 megabyte.

Comment: Why are you considering the overloading taking a bufferSize if don't know a better value than the default of 4096? What about calling Strea.CopyToAsync(fileStream) and let .NET handle buffer sizes for you? Are you having performance issues with such solution?

Comment: I didn't know about the default :) thanks

Comment: Please be aware that the default depends on the .NET version you are using, for .NET 4.5 the default buffer size for Stream.CopyToAsync() is 81920 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158751(v=vs.110).aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1933764/700926