# How do I use C# and ASP.net to proxy a WebRequest?

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest

pretty much...i want to do something like this:

```
Stream Answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream();
Response.OutputStream = Answer;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to proxy a web request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but you can of course copy the data, either synchronously or asynchronously.

- Allocate a buffer (like 4kb in size or so)
- Do a read, which will either return the number of bytes read or 0 if the end of the stream has been reached
- If data was received, write the amount read and loop to the read

Like so:

```
using (Stream answer = webResp.GetResponseStream()) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    for (int read = answer.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); read > 0; read = answer.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) {
        Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/best-way-to-copy-between-two-stream-instances-c/230141#230141) has a method `CopyStream` to copy data between streams (and also indicates the built-in way to do it in .NET 4).

You could do something like:

```
using (stream answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream())
{
    CopyStream(answer, Response.OutputStream); 
    Response.Flush();
}
```