# How to turn stream from Named Pipe into Socket Stream? (in C++ on Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, named-pipes

How to turn stream from Named Pipe into Socket Stream? (in  on Windows) (Share all new data in pipe stream on socket)?

Comment: [Answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/best-way-to-copy-between-two-stream-instances-c "Stackoverflow") already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice thing of named pipes in Windows is that they already work in a network just specifying the server name in the:

```
CreateFile("\\ServerName\pipe\PipeName", ...
```

However, if this not fits your needs, you just have to build a read loop (I suggest OVERLAPPED I/O) that, at every read from the pipe, writes the received data to the socket.