# How to get a MemoryStream from a Stream in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, stream, memorystream

I have the following constructor method which opens a `MemoryStream` from a file path:

```
MemoryStream _ms;

public MyClass(string filePath)
{
    byte[] docBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    _ms = new MemoryStream();
    _ms.Write(docBytes, 0, docBytes.Length);
}
```

I need to change this to accept a `Stream` instead of a file path. Whats the easiest/most efficient way to get a `MemoryStream` from the `Stream` object?

Comment: Once you have the Stream, why bother converting it to a MemoryStream? Can't you just work with the Stream directly?

Comment: I need a MemoryStream due to other dependencies.

Comment: There are also instances where poor performance working with Streams causes a MemoryStream to be more efficient. Like my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399481/azure-function-throwing-parameter-not-valid-calling-image-fromstream-on-large

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you're modifying your class to accept a Stream instead of a filename, don't bother converting to a MemoryStream. Let the underlying Stream handle the operations:

```
public class MyClass
{ 
    Stream _s;

    public MyClass(Stream s) { _s = s; }
}
```

But if you really need a MemoryStream for internal operations, you'll have to copy the data out of the source Stream into the MemoryStream:

```
public MyClass(Stream stream)
{
    _ms = new MemoryStream();
    CopyStream(stream, _ms);
}

// Merged From linked CopyStream below and Jon Skeet's ReadFully example
public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
    int read;
    while((read = input.Read (buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write (buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm presuming that's `> 0` at the end of the while line?

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet - Correct. I got a little delete happy. Fixed.

Comment: looks like one closing parenthesis is missing. should be `while((read = input.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length)) > 0)`

Comment: Might want to add `output.Position = 0;` as the very last line otherwise you'll need to remember to reset it later.

Answer (score 242):

In .NET 4, you can use [Stream.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx) to copy a stream, instead of the home-brew methods listed in the other answers.

```
MemoryStream _ms;

public MyClass(Stream sourceStream)

    _ms = new MemoryStream();
    sourceStream.CopyTo(_ms);
}
```

Comment: Make sure you first set sourceStream.Position = 0;

Comment: You will need to set _ms.Position = 0; prior to using it as well.

Answer (score 69):

Use this:

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
```

This will convert `Stream` to `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply do:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
```

Stream position is 0 and ready to use.

Comment: This is the cleanest and most elegant solution.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all!

Answer (score 3):

You will have to read in all the data from the Stream object into a `byte[]` buffer and then pass that into the `MemoryStream` via its constructor.  It may be better to be more specific about the type of stream object you are using.  `Stream` is very generic and may not implement the `Length` attribute, which is rather useful when reading in data.

Here's some code for you:

```
public MyClass(Stream inputStream) {
    byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[inputStream.Length];
    inputStream.Read(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length);

    _ms = new MemoryStream(inputBuffer);
}
```

If the `Stream` object doesn't implement the `Length` attribute, you will have to implement something like this:

```
public MyClass(Stream inputStream) {
    MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();

    byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[65535];
    int readAmount;
    while((readAmount = inputStream.Read(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length)) > 0)
        outputStream.Write(inputBuffer, 0, readAmount);

    _ms = outputStream;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this combination of extension methods:

```
    public static Stream Copy(this Stream source)
    {
        if (source == null)
            return null;

        long originalPosition = -1;

        if (source.CanSeek)
            originalPosition = source.Position;

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        try
        {
            Copy(source, ms);

            if (originalPosition > -1)
                ms.Seek(originalPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            else
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            return ms;
        }
        catch
        {
            ms.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static void Copy(this Stream source, Stream target)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (target == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("target");

        long originalSourcePosition = -1;
        int count = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];

        if (source.CanSeek)
        {
            originalSourcePosition = source.Position;
            source.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }

        while ((count = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            target.Write(buffer, 0, count);

        if (originalSourcePosition > -1)
        {
            source.Seek(originalSourcePosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[How do I copy the contents of one stream to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/best-way-to-copy-between-two-stream-instances-c)

see that. accept a stream and copy to memory. you should not use `.Length` for just `Stream` because it is not necessarily implemented in every concrete Stream.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void Do(Stream in)
{
    _ms = new MemoryStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    while ((int read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))>=0)
        _ms.Write (buffer, 0, read);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] fileData = null;
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream))
{
    fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
}
```