# Reading very large image from a DB and trying to save it. Getting System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, memory

I do have my project set to 64 bit only.  The file coming from the DB could either be a jpeg or bmp.  Only happens on large files.  Small files work fine.  So I'm figuring it is a memory issue.  Just don't know how to fix.

```
byte[] tImg = dr.Field<byte[]>("IMAGE");
Image imgO = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(tImg));  <----- Errors Here
imgO.Save(outPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
imgO.Dispose();
```

UPDATE::::
Let me re-phrase the issue.  I am reading a BLOB ("IMAGE") from a database.  It is in a DataRow (dr)  The BLOB is over 30GB (hence why I need to write it out as a jpeg/bmp  get it of the server.   Writing it out as WriteAllBytes leaves it unreadable.

Comment: What value is in `tImg`?

Comment: This may also be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399481/azure-function-throwing-parameter-not-valid-calling-image-fromstream-on-large

Comment: It is a blob image coming from the Database.  looking at the solution provided now.  Thanks

Comment: On what line does the error occur? What constitutes *"Large"* and *"Small"*?

Comment: Is dr a DataReader? Why not use dr.GetStream()?

Comment: Over 30 gb?! Is this using `System.Drawing` classes? I know for a fact GDI+ can't handle anything that large.