# Cannot implicitly convert System.IO.Stream to System.IO.MemoryStream. c#

Tags: c#, casting, crystal-reports

This code use to work in VB , can't pinpoint what i'm missing here.

```
System.IO.MemoryStream oStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

if (rptName == "rpt_BankFormatExCopy.rpt" | rptName == "GIS_reportExFormat.rpt" | rptName == "GPFDeductionRepExFormat.rpt")
    oStream = rptObject.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord);
else
    oStream = rptObject.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.Excel);
```

Comment: check this answer please, how to copy one stream to another https://stackoverflow.com/a/3212765/5164252

Comment: @YauhenSampir ReportDocument 
public CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument rptObject;

Comment: please check my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `rptObject` is a `Stream`

You can just use [`CopyTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=netframework-4.7.2) in that case

```
var oStream = new MemoryStream();
Stream stream = null;

if (rptName == "rpt_BankFormatExCopy.rpt" | rptName == "GIS_reportExFormat.rpt" | rptName == "GPFDeductionRepExFormat.rpt")
    stream = rptObject.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord);
else
    stream = rptObject.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.Excel);

stream.CopyTo(oStream);
```