# Using FileStream classes to copy files, why does output not match input?

Tags: c#

Why does the code below not produce an identical output file to the input file?

The idea is to buffer a part of the file in and write it out from a smaller buffer (this is a small program reproducing an error in a larger project where I am streaming a file). When these files are checked in a hex editor comparison tool the output file differs somewhat.

```
fsIn = new FileStream("c:\\wmvs\\Wildlife.wmv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        fsOut = new FileStream("c:\\Users\\public\\documents\\compare\\out.wmv",      FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

        bData = new byte[fsIn.Length / 10];
        bOut = new byte[524288];

        fsIn.Read(bData, 0, bData.Length);

        bool bGo = true;

        while (bGo)
        {
            if (nWrittenOut == bData.Length)
            {
                fsIn.Read(bData, 0, bData.Length);
            }

            if (nWrittenOut + bOut.Length >= bData.Length)
            {
                Array.Clear(bOut, 0, bOut.Length);

                int nWhatsLeft = bData.Length - nWrittenOut;
                Array.Copy(bData, nWrittenOut, bOut, 0, nWhatsLeft);

                fsIn.Read(bData, 0, bData.Length);
                nWrittenOut = 0;
                int nBufPos = nWhatsLeft;

                nWhatsLeft = bOut.Length - nWhatsLeft;
                Array.Copy(bData, nWrittenOut, bOut, nBufPos, nWhatsLeft);
                nWrittenOut += bOut.Length;

            }
            else
            {
                Array.Copy(bData, nWrittenOut, bOut, 0, bOut.Length);
                nWrittenOut += bOut.Length;
            }

            fsOut.Write(bOut, 0, bOut.Length);
            fsOut.Flush();

            if (fsOut.Position >= fsIn.Length)
                bGo = false;
        }

    }
```

I have tried all the below answers and nothing works. It must be my logic in the code. However I cannot see the problem ???? It seems I am missing a whole chunk in the output file eqivalent to the length of bOut.

Comment: If the goal is to copy a file I would use any of the copy mechanisms available.. I think there's like a File.Copy

If it's to read in a stream and write out another stream, then I am baffled as to the lot of code you have in here..

Comment: A more descriptive question title will probably yield a lot more answers.

Comment: Describing how that data is off would help.  Have the new-lines been changed?  Zero characters written into the file?  etc.  Be specific, and as for your question title, it is terribly bad.  This is not your personal forum.

Comment: Perhaps it would also help if you give examples of how the hex comparisons differ...

Comment: Research the `using` statement for your first two lines to guarantee closure of the files and release of the associated resources.

Comment: OK I am using Stream instead of FileStream and using BinaryReader and writer. On checking the return values of fsIn.Read() I found that Im only reading in 6 bytes in the second If statement inside the loop. I can simply correct this by reading again until I get the original length I requested, however I would like to understand why Im only getting 6 bytes as opposed to bData.Length. I thought that using BinaryReader and Stream instead would stop any characters stopping the read from working as suggested by others in their answers. Sorry for the question title but am new here....

Comment: I have tried all the below answers and nothing works. It must be my logic in the code. However I cannot see the problem ???? It seems I am missing a whole chunk in the output file eqivalent to the length of bOut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you're doing, but why don't you try this, it's likely that reading and writing through a FileStream might not be encoding agnostic, so stick with a stream and just pass bytes along:

```
using (Stream inStream = File.Open(inFilePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (Stream outStream = File.Create(outFilePath))
    {
        while (inStream.Position < inStream.Length)
        {
            outStream.WriteByte((byte)inStream.ReadByte());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is great if you want to watch the individual bytes crawl from a to b. In other words: It's slow as hell. Better use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128 -- or maybe even just http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx

Comment: @dtb: Just trying to keep the example as simple as possible for the poster, he can figure out to use a set size buffer after he gets it working to begin with I figure. And the File.Copy I already suggested in comment above..

Comment: @dtb, Note the overload of `.CopyTo()` which allows for a user-specified buffer size.

Answer (score 1):

it's probably read/writing in Text mode, so that any 0x0A in encounters in the binary file is being converted to a CR/LF.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` to avoid the `Environment.NewLine` translation that you are being "provided."

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the return value of your `fsIn.Read` method.  The `Read` method will not always read the number of bytes that you requested.  If you are seeing extra "0" bytes in the results then this is probably the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not checking return value of `fsIn.Read()`? I have no (developer) experience with Windows platform, but can you *always* be sure that exactly this number of bytes will be read? What about the end of file? :)