# Interconnect streams

Tags: c#, .net, file, stream, io

I have this scenario:

```
DownloadLibrary.GetData(Stream targetStream);
SaveLibrary.WriteData(Stream sourceStream);
```

I want to send the data that targetStream collects to the sourceStream. I've come up with some solutions but I cannot find a way to connect those streams directly.

What I'm trying to achieve is send the data from targetStream to sourceStream without buffer the targetStream first.

How can it be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't cross the streams!!! ... Sorry. Couldn't help myself.

Comment: @Mike "Don't cross the streams!!!" :)

Comment: "excuse me Egon? You said crossing the streams was bad!" Oh I love that movie!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is built in support (from .Net 4.0) in `Stream` for copying one stream to another via `CopyTo`, e.g.:

```
stream1.CopyTo(stream2)
```

Example:

```
[Test]
public void test()
{
    string inString = "bling";

    byte[] inBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inString);

    Stream stream1 = new MemoryStream(inBuffer);
    Stream stream2 = new MemoryStream();

    //Copy stream 1 to stream 2
    stream1.CopyTo(stream2);

    byte[] outBuffer = new byte[inBuffer.Length];

    stream2.Position = 0;        
    stream2.Read(outBuffer, 0, outBuffer.Length);

    string outString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(outBuffer);

    Assert.AreEqual(inString, outString, "inString equals outString.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The built-in CopyTo method referred to in chibacity's answer is available from .NET 4.0.

For earlier versions look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/best-way-to-copy-between-two-stream-instances-c).