# Write PDF stream to response stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

If I have a pdf file as a Stream, how can I write it to the response output stream?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since you are using MVC, the best way is to use `FileStreamResult`:

```
return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf")
{
    FileDownloadName = "file.pdf"
};
```

Playing with `Response.Write` or `Response.OutputStream` from your controller is non-idiomatic and there's no reason to write your own ActionResult when one already exists.

Answer (score 12):

One way to do it is as follows:

```
//assuming you have your FileStream handle already - named fs
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
long count = 0;

while ((count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
    response.Flush();
}
```

You can also use GZIP compression to speed the transfer of the file to the client (less bytes streamed).

Comment: It's better to just set up compression of dynamic content in IIS7 config so it happens across the board.

Comment: @Talljoe - agreed I'd set it up that way as well, I should have been more clear

Comment: Eh... does this even work? System.IO.Stream.Write(byte[], int, int) you have count as a long = no workie.

Answer (score 7):

In asp.net this is the way to download a pdf file

```
    Dim MyFileStream As FileStream
    Dim FileSize As Long

    MyFileStream = New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)
    FileSize = MyFileStream.Length

    Dim Buffer(CInt(FileSize)) As Byte
    MyFileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, CInt(FileSize))
    MyFileStream.Close()

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.OutputStream.Write(Buffer, 0, FileSize)
    Response.Flush()
    Response.Close()
```

Comment: I would like this answer a lot more if it was written in c# like the question asks

Comment: Downvote because FileStream is not automatically disposed (try/finally or using).

Answer (score 4):

The HTTP Response is a stream exposed to you through the `HttpContext.Response.OutputStream` property, so if you have the PDF file in a stream you can simply copy the data from one stream to the other:

```
CopyStream(pdfStream, response.OutputStream);
```

For an implementation of `CopyStream` see [Best way to copy between two Stream instances - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/best-way-to-copy-between-two-stream-instances-c)

Answer (score -2):

Please try this one:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Context.Response.Buffer = false;
        FileStream inStr = null;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        long byteCount; inStr = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\Downloads\sample.pdf");
        while ((byteCount = inStr.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
            if (Context.Response.IsClientConnected) {
                Context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                Context.Response.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why the length of byte array is 1024? What if its size is more than you defined ?