# Write PDF stream to response stream

Tags: asp.net

I am having problems when I tried  to run the following code from my asp.net page. The code is from  another post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828315/write-pdf-stream-to-response-stream). When the Test.pdf file is located in my local drive, I am not able to open the file when the open button on the dialog box is clicked. When, the save button is clicked, the file tries in as myAspPageName.pdf in "C:\Downloads" the operation goes on for ever without actually saving anything.

I am sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks for any help. Is there a better way of doing the same thing?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{         
    Context.Response.Buffer = false;         
    FileStream inStr = null;         
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];         
    long byteCount; inStr = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Downloads\Test.pdf");         
    while ((byteCount = inStr.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) 
    {    
        if (Context.Response.IsClientConnected) 
        { 
            Context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Context.Response.Flush();             
        }        
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Response.WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile.aspx) instead of all the buffer work.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{         
    Context.Response.WriteFile(@"C:\Downloads\Test.pdf"); 
}
```

Comment: Response.TransmitFile is more efficient in resources - it doesn't buffer the file into memory.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [`HttpResponse.TransmitFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy.aspx) (ASP.NET >= 2.0), especially for large files because it writes the file without buffering it into server memory.

Also, make sure you always set the [`Response.ContentType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525208.aspx) property to the appropriate MIME type or browsers will sometimes have trouble with downloading your files correctly, especially if you are writing the file from a handler:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
```