# How to use pdf.js in asp.net application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, pdf, pdf.js

I want to know how to use [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) in my asp.net application.

all what i want to do is open the data which are in `byte[]` in an area (pdf) a**nd write my notes and sign on the pdf the save the result in byte[]**

Comment: just provide byte[] as result of an URL (Response.Write()...). Client side in your page just point to that URL.

Comment: @Adriano:Could u provide more details, this's the first time i use it , and i want some steps to help me

Comment: It depends where you are...do you have a page that replies byte[] with PDF content? If not then start, for example, with [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916647/write-pdf-stream-to-response-stream). When you have that...just point to that URL and PDF.JS should render it (as it is in PDF.JS examples).

Comment: @adriano-repetti i am not getting examples of pdf.js in MVC..please help me.

Comment: @Archana no need examples in MVC, it's just some scripts client side (see PDF.js docs and also [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654577/html-embedded-pdf-iframe/19654875#19654875)) and return File("path to your pdf") in your controller method (as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-mvc)).