# Azure download blob SAS - confirm please

Tags: azure

I would like to confirm my code and see if I'm on the right path here..

From my view i list all the blobs that belong to the user.
The user can click on one of these blobs and start download it immediately and directly from blob storage itself.

Here is the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Delamapp.CloudStorageServices.UploadEntity>

@foreach (var file in Model)
{
<a href='@Url.Action("DownloadFileTest", "Folder", new { blobName = file.BlobName,        fileName = file.FileName, fileExtension = file.FileExtension })'

@file.FileName.PreviewString(file.FileName, file.FileExtension)@file.FileExtension
}
```

Here is the download function:

```
   public void DownloadFileTest(string blobName, string fileName, string fileExtension)
    {
       //Get SAS url
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = CloudStorageServices.GetCloudBlobsContainer();
        CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

        var sas = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5),
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(3),
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read
        });

        string blobSasUri = (string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}{1}", blob.Uri, sas));

        //Download Blob through SAS url
        CloudBlockBlob blobSas = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(blobSasUri));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            blobSas.DownloadToStream(ms);
            byte[] data = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Position = 0;
            ms.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

            Response.ContentType = blobSas.Properties.ContentType;
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=" + fileName + fileExtension);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", (blobSas.Properties.Length).ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

1. Am i downloading directly from the blob storage now?
2. Within the using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()), what does this code do? Am i using something that is not needed? Should i be using these? Ms.position, response.. etc.
3. Download method is public which means it can be called from the url. If i want to prevent this, can i use a linq method in the start and check if the blob the user is trying to download is in his/hers account? Would that be enough?
4. I want users to be able to download their own blobs at anytime. Setting starttime/endtime is not need then, right? Can i just delete those lines?

**Update**

After I updated the storage client library, I started to get the following error.

FOUND CONFLICTS -----

```
  1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1635,5): warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.1.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.1.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Spatial" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.1.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.1.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am i downloading directly from the blob storage now?

No. Your code running on the server is downloading the blob and then server is streaming the code back to your client. To directly download from blob storage, replace the following lines of code:

```
// Download Blob through SAS url
CloudBlockBlob blobSas = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(blobSasUri));
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    blobSas.DownloadToStream(ms);
    byte[] data = new byte[ms.Length];
    ms.Position = 0;
    ms.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    Response.ContentType = blobSas.Properties.ContentType;
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=" + fileName + fileExtension);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", (blobSas.Properties.Length).ToString());
    Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
    Response.End();
}
```

with

```
// Download Blob through SAS url
Redirect(blobSasUri);
```

> Within the using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()), what does
>   this code do? Am i using something that is not needed? Should i be
>   using these? Ms.position, response.. etc.

I think the code is fine.

> Download method is public which means it can be called from the url.
>   If i want to prevent this, can i use a linq method in the start and
>   check if the blob the user is trying to download is in his/hers
>   account? Would that be enough?

Without knowing more details, I don't think this can be answered.

> I want users to be able to download their own blobs at anytime.
>   Setting starttime/endtime is not need then, right? Can i just delete
>   those lines?

You could. But it is not recommended. At the end of the day, SAS URL is a URL and your users may share with some other folks who are not supposed to download the images. By keeping the expiry date in the SAS URL, you're preventing misuse of the URL.

Comment: Ahaaa now i get, lol embarrassing.

Im able to download the blob now but im struggling with
new SharedAccessBlobHeaders()
                {
                    ContentDisposition = "attachment; filename=file-name"
                });
Where do you get SharedAccessBlobHeaders from? Currently it says it cant be found in the namespace..

Also, wouldnt i need to set ContentType and such?

Comment: You would need to use storage client library version 3.0+. You can download/install using Nuget from here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/. Once content disposition is set, you don't need to worry about content type. The file will automatically be downloaded.

Comment: Any way to set it without updating from 2.0.4 to 4.0? Im getting all kinds of errors in my project now..



Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client, Version=5.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf385ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Don't update to 4.0. Instead trying updating to version 3.x.x (http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/3.2.1). There's a chance that you may still get this error and in that case, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457846/missing-microsoft-data-services-client-version-5-6-on-azure-websites. HTH.

Comment: Ive tried all the 3.x noone works. I also reinstalled the dataserviceclient but that didnt help either. Look at my error message above, (edited my question) This appears when i build my solution after installing all the items you said. I can still run it, but it fails at linq questions

Comment: WCF data service client 5.6.1

Comment: First, please re-edit your question and put the old contents back. With the changes you have done, the whole context of question is gone. Then update your question and add this error message you're getting. Now coming on to your problem, you would need to add some assembly binding statements in your web.config file. The reason you're getting the error is because your code is referencing latest version of assemblies however storage client library is looking for older versions. By adding this assembly binding statements, you instruct the storage client library to use the version that you have.

Comment: Sorry im new to stackoverflow. Now how would i take my my old post back? is it possible? Im kinda panicked right now thats why its all messed up..

Also.. How would i add assembly binding to my webconfig? I have no idea what im doing right now.

Is there no way to do this in version 2.x? Im kinda spooked right now

The reason i was using 2.x is because someone said to me the emaltor isnt working for the newer versions? Is that true? How can it not be added to the newer versions? Whats the deal with all these versions not working corretly'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54273/discussion-between-gaurav-mantri-and-user3276084).