# Open PDF file with Save As option in asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, webforms

I have list of PDF files on website (asp.net webforms). i want to open them with Save As option rather than it downlaods directly.

I tried to add `download` property to the link which didn't work. only was around seems to be HTTPHandler for `*.pdf` request.

I saw a piece of code for MVC based example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828315/write-pdf-stream-to-response-stream)

```
return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf")
{
    FileDownloadName = "file.pdf"
};
```

How can i convert this to HTTPHandler in as.net webform so that it open pdf files with Save As option.

I want to do it in a way so that when ever user click on any pdf file at that time Handler should come into action.

OR

I can create another file handlePDF.aspx and write code there also and will change link of pdf file to below

```
<a href="handlePDF.aspx?file=file1.pdf">File One </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you are trying to do is when they click on the file download link it pops up with `save as` or `open` dialog box, this is to do with the user's browser configuration. In the case of PDF's i believe Firefox has `open in tab` as the default option. If you try to push the file as a file stream it will more than likely just load it in a new tab as well.

tl;dr: Client side issue

Comment: Cant use that option as it is client request we cant configure each browser. I want to avoid it as it is heavy on server as sending out pdf as a stream take server resources.

Comment: Have you tried the `<a href="handlePDF.aspx?file=file1.pdf" download target="_blank">File One </a>` approach?

Comment: I have to create `handlePDF.aspx` first otherwise it will get page not found error. I have already tried `download target="_blank"` previously on the link it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Serving PDF files are usually handled by an `HttpHandler`. That is, unless they can be served straight from the file system by the `StaticHandler`...

The key thing that is needed in order for the browser to raise the "Open or save" dialog is the `Content-Disposition` header in the response.

Here is an (untested) implementation that should get you on the right track:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string fileName = context.Request.QueryString["file"];
    if(fileName == null || fileName == "")
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The file argument cannot be null or empty");
    }

    // fetch file here from db/filesystem/other storage
    byte[] fileBytes = LoadFileBytes(fileName);

    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
}
```

If you want to avoid buffering the whole file in memory, this might also work (requires .Net 4.0 for the `CopyTo` method on the stream):

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string fileName = context.Request.QueryString["file"];
    if(fileName == null || fileName == "")
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The file argument cannot be null or empty");
    }

    // fetch file stream from db/filesystem/other storage
    Stream fileStream = GetFileStream(fileName);

    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    fileStream.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
}
```