# C# - File.Copy() throws "Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service" exception

Tags: c#, io, mscorlib

```
System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFilePath, destinationFilePath)
```

intermittently throws an `IOExeception`.

The exception says:

> Exception Thrown: "System.IO.IOException" in mscorlib.dll.
>
> Additional Information: Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.

I am calling this code on machine A. `sourceFilePath` is on machine B. `destinationFilePath` is on machine C.

This issue is not consistently reproducible.

Comment: Any patterns as it relates to the size of the files being copied? What I mean is does it happen more often on larger files? Also what is the size (in MB) of files being copied where it does occur?

Comment: Hi Igor. Based on what I have observed I think the rate of occurrence of the issue definitely correlates the file size. The size of files being copied where this issue occurs is 600 ~ 700 MB.

Comment: `File.Copy` uses the underlying windows API method to execute the copy. I am not sure what the actual implementation actually is but maybe it does not execute the copy in chunks. I would try changing your code around and opening up 2 file streams (1 to read, 1 to write), execute a loop and read and write in chunks until the content has been copied over.

Comment: Here are some links with code you could try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1247042/1260204, http://stackoverflow.com/a/6216495/1260204, http://stackoverflow.com/a/230141/1260204,

Answer (score 0):

This is more than likely a memory issue on your machine.  I'd start by looking at the size of your paging file.

Comment: Thank you Charles.  Which machine is likely to have the memory issue? A, B or C?

Comment: I would say it is the one that is throwing the error.  It sounds like machine A.  That is the one you are executing the code from, correct?