# How to write a Stream to file?

Tags: vb.net, stream, .net-2.0

I have an embedded DLL in my app and I need to write it to the filesystem at runtime. I have this so far:

```
Dim _assembly As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
Dim _rawstream As Stream = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyFile.dll")
```

I just need to write _rawstream to a file now.

EDIT: This has to be .NET Framework 2 and CopyTo does not exist :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(output file, My.Resources.resourcename, False)
```

Answer (score 9):

Use a [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) and write to it.

```
Dim fs As new FileStream("path to new file.dll", FileMode.Create)

_rawstream.CopyTo(fs)
```

Edit:

For pre 4.0 see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/best-way-to-copy-between-two-stream-instances-c-sharp).

Comment: @SixHouse - Added link to a pre 4.0 option.

Answer (score 1):

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite("MyFile.bin"))
{
    _rawstream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

EDIT: Oops, sorry, that's C# but the VB should be similar