# Image loss quality after upload via HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(imgPath)

Tags: c#, image, image-uploading, httpfilecollection

I'm working in a project that doesn't use much of the .net framework and instead work with `Request.Form` posts.

The code that was being used to save the images (this work, but loss quality) is this one:

```
files[0].SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../uploads/") + filename);
```

So I tried to change to this, but now it doesn't even save the image. (the `uploadStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)` comes with the value of 0.

```
string imagePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../uploads/") + filename;
using (BinaryReader uploadStream = new BinaryReader(files[0].InputStream))
{
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        int read;
        while ((read = uploadStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

I built this code basing myself on the question/answers of [Image upload without loss of quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171918/image-upload-without-loss-of-quality). I'm using `.net 4.0` on the application.

---

Is there another way, or what I was doing is the right way and I just missed something? PS: I don't get any error and on the database, I save the correct information, but I don't get the file on the folder. The upload to that folder works, since it work with the `SaveAs()` method.

PS: I may be wrong, about SaveAs being the reason to loss of quality on the image, but the `files[0]` come right from the `HttpFileCollection` and the upload is only there.

Comment: The image that I'm testing is a `jpg` image with `1.24MB` and `1920x460`.