# Upload images: reduce resolution without loosing quality (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, bitmap, alamofire, image-uploading

I have user gallery at remote areas where internet speed is limited. And, they can upload multiple documents when asked.

In that case, when I am not suppressing the document image.. it takes time to upload the document and on the other hand, when I do, document loose readability.

So, here, I am finding the way to upload multiple documents with full resolution but without losing quality.

And, document image can be in any format jpg, jpeg, png etc.

Thanks in advance for your help.

I check this [Image upload without loss of quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171918/image-upload-without-loss-of-quality) but didn't help it.

Answer (score 0):

The link is .NET, you need Swift, right?

You have a image named "originalImage". The code below compress this image and create a new, smaller one with same resolution. The value (0.8) is compression level.

Upload "compressedImage" to server.

```
let compressedImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(originalImage, 0.8)
```

Comment: But, it is affecting quality as second parameter for this function is for quality.

Comment: Not much. You can put breakpoint and preview UIImages. Probably you can't see any difference.

Comment: I have tried this...Still, I will check it again. Thanks