# How Write a Stream into a xml file in Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, stream, isolatedstorage, onedrive

I'm trying to implement SkyDrive backup into my app. Everything is working fine except I have no idea how to easily save stream (with downloaded backup from SkyDrive) into Isolated Storarage.

I know that I could deserilaze the stream and than save it, but it would unnecessarily complicated.

So, here's my problem:

I have a Stream with the file from SkyDrive and I need to save it into IsolatedStorage as file 'Settings.XML'.

So basicly I need to Write the 'stream' into Settings.xml file in Isolated Storage

```
        static void client_DownloadCompleted(object sender, LiveDownloadCompletedEventArgs e, string saveToPath)
    {
        Stream stream = e.Result; //Need to write this into IS

        try
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(saveToPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    //How to save it?

                }
            }
        }...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the steam's CopyTo() method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(saveToPath, FileMode.Create))    
{    
  stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The quickest and simplest thung to do is to copy the bytes block by block from one stream to the next - see the accepted answer in [How do I copy the contents of one stream to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/best-way-to-copy-between-two-stream-instances-c-sharp)

---

However, if there is any chance that the network stream will be corrupt or contain invalid data, then it might be worth deserializing the stream and validating before you save it.

Comment: Ok, I'll copy the content of SkyDrive stream into local IsolatedStorage Stream. But how will I save it then (into file)?

Comment: That iso stream in your code sample is backed by a file :) that's what openFile gives you.

Comment: `using` means that `Dispose()` will be called on the stream - which will mean `Close()` happens