# Write XML stream to an xml file

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-7, xmlhttprequest, linq-to-xml

I know this must be a rookie question, but how do i accomplish that?
Because from what i have seen here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter or at XMLWriter  is not helping me, because i just want to save all, not write specific lines.

Basically i have an httpRequest that returns back an XML response. I am getting that in a stream, and from that i want to save it to an xml file, for later use. 
Part of the code:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
            string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();

            XDocument blabla = XDocument.Parse(responseString);

            // Here is where the saving to a file should occur

            streamResponse.Close();
            streamRead.Close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need to parse the file? In .NET 4 you can just write it directly to disk using a file stream like this:

```
using (var fileStream = File.Create("file.xml"))
{
    streamResponse.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

If you are using an earlier version of the .NET framework, you can use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/best-way-to-copy-between-two-stream-instances-c-sharp) to copy data from one stream to another.

Comment: No overload for method 'CopyTo' takes 1 argument

Comment: I updated my answer to describe how to do it in an earlier version of .NET

Comment: @observ: Then say or tag that, not ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save.aspx

Should help you get the job done!

Answer (score 0):

As you already have the XML response as a string, I think what you need is to use a [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ssew6tk) class to write the response string straight to a file.

There is an MSDN example of its use here: [How to: Write Text to a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w)