# Read a PDF into a string or byte[] and write that string/byte[] back to disk

Tags: c#, file, pdf

I am having a problem in my app where it reads a PDF from disk, and then has to write it back to a different location later.

The emitted file is not a valid PDF anymore.

In very simplified form, I have tried reading/writing it using

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\myfile.pdf");
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\output.pdf", bytes);
```

and

```
var input = new StreamReader(@"c:\myfile.pdf").ReadToEnd();
File.WriteAllText("c:\output.pdf", input);
```

... and about 100 permutations of the above with various encodings being specified.  None of the output files were valid PDFs.

Can someone please lend a hand?  Many thanks!!

Comment: `File.Copy` not working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/best-way-to-copy-between-two-stream-instances

Comment: The first snippet that you posted *will* work. Your input PDF must be incorrect to begin with.

Comment: Also note the distinction between text and bytes! And the necessity to dispose your objects.

Answer (score 3):

In C#/.Net 4.0:

```
using (var i = new FileStream(@"input.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
   using (var o = File.Create(@"output.pdf"))
      i.CopyTo(o);
```

If you *insist* on having the `byte[]` first:

```
using (var i = new FileStream(@"input.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
   using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
        i.CopyTo(ms);
        byte[] rawdata = ms.GetBuffer();

        using (var o = File.Create(@"output.pdf"))
           ms.CopyTo(o);
   }
```

The memory stream may need to be `ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Origin)` or something like that before the second CopyTo. look it up, or try it out

Comment: @usr Depends on the use. If the instream is going to be a network stream, this is a bit ... _impossibru_. Likely this is about what the OP is trying to do, otherwise File.Copy is clearly the winner

Comment: Ok, I agree for the case of arbitrary streams.

Comment: Although I think @JayRiggs answer is technically the "correct answer", given the phrasing of the question, this is a "better" answer, as it's a lot more efficient than reading the whole file into a byte array and blasting it back out.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  The output file is 0 bytes, however.

Comment: @TimH Did you add the `Seek`? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.seek.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You're using `File.WriteAllText` to write your file out.

Try [`File.WriteAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx).

Comment: This. You need to match up read/write "types" - reading as bytes and writing as text won't work.

Comment: I believe that each of my code samples does that.  First sample uses byte[], second sample uses string.  Am I missing something?