# FTP Request - Response: Upload - Download. Which Stream do I have to use?

Tags: c#, ftp, stream

I already asked a question about ftp-upload ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27575933/stream-copyto-how-do-i-get-the-sent-bytes))
And I thought I understood it,
**BUT**:

If I use the following code to upload a file, can I change the Streams to download it?

```
string sourcePath = sourceToDestinationPair.Key;
string destinationPath = sourceToDestinationPair.Value;
string fileName = new FileInfo(sourcePath).Name;

Console.WriteLine("Create WebRequest: (Upload) " + destinationPath + "//" + fileName);

FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destinationPath + "//" + fileName);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Manager._user, Manager._password);

var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (Stream source = File.OpenRead(sourcePath))
     {
          using (var destination = new StreamWithTransferSpeed(request.GetRequestStream(), bGWorkerUpload, source.Length, fileName))//request.ContentLength))
          {
               source.CopyTo(destination);
          }
     }
Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);
response.Close();
```

**Upload:**
source-Stream = File.OpenRead(file);
destination-Stream = WebRequest.GetRequestStream;

**Dwonload;:**
source-Stream = Web..... ????
destination-Stream = File.OpenWrite(file);

I thought the source-Stream at a Download is `WebResponse.GetResponseStream();`, but a exception is thrown:
`"System.NotSupportedException": This Stream do not support any search pattern`
That's what I try:

```
string sourcePath = sourceToDestinationPair.Key;
string destinationPath = sourceToDestinationPair.Value;
string fileName = new FileInfo(sourcePath).Name;

Console.WriteLine("Create WebRequest: (Download) " + destinationPath + "//" + fileName);
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destinationPath + "//" + fileName);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Manager._user, Manager._password);

var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (var source = new StreamWithTransferSpeed(response.GetResponseStream(), bGWorkerDownload, response.GetResponseStream().Length, fileName))
{
     using (var destination = File.OpenWrite(sourcePath))//request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), bGWorkerDownload, request.GetResponse().ContentLength, fileName))
     {
          source.CopyTo(destination);
     }
}
Console.WriteLine("Download File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);
response.Close();
```

`StreamWithTransferSpeed` is an overwritten Stream-Class, as you can see at the url above.

I dont know what I am doing here...

Thanks for help.

---

**EDIT:**
I think the `this.ReportProgress`-Method is more often invokes as the `this.innerStream.Read`-Method, but I dont know why and I dont know how to change it:

```
public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    this.ReportProgress(count);
    return this.innerStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
}
```

This is the `Write`-Method and it works well:

```
public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    this.innerStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    this.ReportProgress(count);
}
```

I dont know why, but I reckon that the `this.ReportProgess`-Method also have to be below the `this.innerStream.Read`-Method as in the `Write`-Method, **BUT** I dont know how to cache the `Read`-Method and return it after the ReportProgress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is

```
response.GetResponseStream().Length
```

either because this type of Stream doesn't support the `Length` property or, more likely, you're calling `GetResponseStream` twice on the same response object. I guess you can do this only once and then use this Stream a single time.

You should use

```
response.ContentLength
```

instead to get the number of bytes for your StreamWithTransferSpeed.

Comment: Thanks. For now it works, but at the moment I add `this.ReportProgress(count);` at the `StreamWithTransferSpeed.Read(..)` or `.ReadByte(..)` the progess-value is negativ, because the `response.ContentLength` = -1. Any Idea why?

Comment: Because your FTP server doesn't tell you the file size. Try to find out the size before downloading using WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;

Comment: I think the `this.ReportProgress(count);` is not on the correct position. `ftpContentLength (WRM.Ftp.GetFileSize;)` is correct, but the `e.ProgressPercentage` runs over 100% (214%). It is the same equation as the equation at the upload. I think this `public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            this.ReportProgress(count);
            return this.innerStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        }` is not correct.

Comment: I added a breakpoint and noticed that `this.totalBytes` increase above the `ContentLength`. Atm I don't know why. I will check this tomorrow. It would be nice, when we can create a new chat again.