# Idiomatic way to copy content from one connection to another in `R`?

Tags: r

In `R`, what is the best way to copy all content from one [connection](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/connections) to another connection? In `C#`, such functionality appears to be provided by the [`Steam.copyTo()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/how-do-i-copy-the-contents-of-one-stream-to-another).

I know that this could be performed manually, using [read and write functions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readBin.html) in a loop. 
For example, consider this script to `gzip` a file (here, the DESCRIPTION file from the base package):

```
file_to_be_gziped <- system.file("DESCRIPTION", package = "base")
in_connection <- file(file_to_be_gziped, open = "rb", raw = TRUE)
out_connection <- gzfile("DESCRIPTION.gz", open = "wb")
while(length(buf <- readBin(in_connection, "raw", n = 1024*1024))) {
  writeBin(buf, out_connection)
}
close(in_connection)
close(out_connection)
```

However, such an approach is not only very lengthy but also error prone and probably inefficient (blocking).

How can this be achieved in `R` in a concise, expressive and efficient way?