# DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject pass a different type of object

Tags: c#, json, datacontractjsonserializer

I have a problem, a certain http API can return two different types of JSON objects. Unfortunately I have to live with it. I have to work with it from .NET 3.5 code, and I use `DataContractJsonSerializer` to deserialize the responses from the service. This is a constraint as well - I can't use anything else for json serialization. When I try to deserialize object of Type 1 from json object of Type 2 `DataContractJsonSerializer` just succeeds - only all the properties of the object are set to default values. Is there any way to make it fail?

```
ResponseDto Get<ResponseDto>(string requestUrl)
{
    // skip all the HttpWebRequest bullshit
    try
    {
       var response = request.GetResponse();
       if (response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Ok)
       {
          var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ResponseDto));

          // I would like this line to fail somehow, give me null back, whatever
          var responseDto = (ResponseDto)serializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());

          // this never happens now
          if (responseDto == null)
          {
             var otherResponseSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SecondResponseDto));
            // SecondResponseDto is always fixed type
             var otherResponse = (SecondResponseDto)otherResponseSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());

             // this typically would throw an exception
             HandleOtherResponse(otherResponse);

             return default(ResponseDto);
          }
       } 
    }
    catch(WebException e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: How different are the responses?  Can you share a simplified example?

Comment: You can set `[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]` on the distinct members of `ResponseDto` and `SecondResponseDto`, and an exception will be thrown if the member is not present.  But as an aside, does getting and reading from the response stream **twice** actually work?  That sort of surprises me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a more basic problem here than making `serializer.ReadObject()` return an error: the `Stream` returned from [`WebResponse.GetResponseStream()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.getresponsestream.aspx) cannot be repositioned and read from a second time.  Thus in general you will need to copy the response into some local buffer and query what was returned.  There are at least two approaches to this.

**Firstly**, you could copy the response into a local `MemoryStream` and attempt to deserialize into `ResponseDto`.  Then if that fails, try `SecondResponseDto`.  To distinguish between the two types during deserialization, you can mark distinguishing properties with [`[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.isrequired.aspx).

Say for instance `ResponseDto` has a member `data` while `SecondResponseDto` has a member `results`.  You could define them as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class ResponseDto
{
    [DataMember(Name = "data", IsRequired = true)]
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class SecondResponseDto
{
    [DataMember(Name = "results", IsRequired = true)]
    public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
}
```

And then deserialize as follows:

```
ResponseDto response1;
SecondResponseDto response2;

var copyStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            responseStream.CopyTo(copyStream);
        }
    }
}

try
{
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ResponseDto));
    copyStream.Position = 0L;
    response1 = (ResponseDto)serializer.ReadObject(copyStream);
}
catch (SerializationException)
{
    response1 = null;
}

if (response1 != null)
    response2 = null;
else
{
    try
    {
        var otherResponseSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SecondResponseDto));
        copyStream.Position = 0L;
        response2 = (SecondResponseDto)otherResponseSerializer.ReadObject(copyStream);
    }
    catch (SerializationException)
    {
        response2 = null;
    }
}
```

Where `CopyTo()` is an extension method adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/230141/3744182) by [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1490/nick):

```
public static class StreamExtensions
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/how-do-i-copy-the-contents-of-one-stream-to-another
    public static void CopyTo(this Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

(This extension method is only required in .Net 3.5 as .Net 4.0 and later have [`Stream.CopyTo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx) built in.)

The distinguishing data member(s) do not need to be present on the root data contract in this solution.  As long as `[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]` is present somewhere in the object graph the serializer will throw an exception if the object is present but the marked data member is not.

**Secondly**, you could load the response into an intermediate `XElement` using an `XmlReader` returned by [`JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.jsonreaderwriterfactory.createjsonreader.aspx) and query the returned results keeping in mind the mapping from JSON to XML defined in [Mapping Between JSON and XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/mapping-between-json-and-xml).  Then deserialize the intermediate XML to the appropriate type depending on the elements present.  In the case above your code might look like:

```
ResponseDto response1 = null;
SecondResponseDto response2 = null;

XElement root = null;

using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(responseStream, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max))
        {
            root = XElement.Load(reader);
        }
    }
}

// Replace the Where queries below with something appropriate to your actual JSON.

if (root != null && root.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "data").Any())
{
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ResponseDto));
    response1 = (ResponseDto)serializer.ReadObject(root.CreateReader());
}
else if (root != null && root.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "results").Any())
{
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SecondResponseDto));
    response2 = (SecondResponseDto)serializer.ReadObject(root.CreateReader());
}
```

This solution takes advantage of the fact that `DataContractJsonSerializer` shares a code base with `DataContractSerializer` and actually works by internally translating the JSON to XML on the fly during deserialization.  With this solution it is no longer required to mark distinguishing data members with `IsRequired = true`.

Comment: I know about the Stream repositioning, that wasn't the part of the question since I know how to solve it