# Save stream of savefiledialog in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, savefiledialog

In my wpf app I have an "Export" button that suppose to save some json file to chosen path.

I mean my question is how to write the file, let's say he has the path `D:\somefile.json` to the chosen location that the user chose from save dualog?

Here my code:

```
void Export_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Stream myStream;
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Json files (*.json)|*.json";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                // Code to write the stream goes here.
                myStream.Close();
            }
}
```

This should be something like:

`Copy(StreamOf(D:\somefile.json),ChosenPath)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy the contents of one stream to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/how-do-i-copy-the-contents-of-one-stream-to-another)

Comment: @Flufy do you just want to save file as json?

Comment: You can also do (assuming you serialized your json as string) File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, jsonString);

Comment: I'm writing a json **File** not a string of json

Comment: plz post answers

Comment: `System.IO.File.Copy(@"D:\somefile.json", saveFileDialog1.FileName);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SaveFileDialog sf = new SaveFileDialog();
 sf.Filter = "Json files (*.json)|*.json";
 sf.FilterIndex = 2;
 sf.RestoreDirectory = true;
 if (sf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {                  
     System.IO.File.Copy(@"D:\somefile.json", sf.FileName, true);   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **File.copy**

```
public static void Copy(
string sourceFileName,
string destFileName)
```

for more info you can visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx