# C#: how to read a line from a stream and then start reading it from beginning?

Tags: c#, stream, readline

I need to read the first line from a stream to determine file's encoding, and then recreate the stream with that Encoding

The following code does not work correctly:

```
var r = response.GetResponseStream();
var sr = new StreamReader(r);
string firstLine =  sr.ReadLine();
string encoding = GetEncodingFromFirstLine(firstLine);
string text = new StreamReader(r, Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding)).ReadToEnd();
```

The text variable doesn't contain the whole text. For some reason the first line and several lines after it are skipped.

I tried everything: closing the StreamReader, resetting it, calling a separate GetResponseStream... but nothing worked.

I can't get the response stream again as I'm getting this file from the internet, and redownloading it again would be bad performance wise.

**Update**

Here's what GetEncodingFromFirstLine() looks like:

```
public static string GetEncodingFromFirstLine(string line)
{
    int encodingIndex = line.IndexOf("encoding=");
    if (encodingIndex == -1)
    {
        return "utf-8";
    }
    return line.Substring(encodingIndex + "encoding=".Length).Replace("\"", "").Replace("'", "").Replace("?", "").Replace(">", "");
}

...

// true
Assert.AreEqual("windows-1251", GetEncodingFromFirstLine(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""windows-1251""?>"));
```

** Update 2 **

I'm working with XML files, and the text variable is parsed as XML:

```
var feedItems = XElement.Parse(text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question here:

[How can I read an Http response stream twice in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147941/how-can-i-read-an-http-response-stream-twice-in-c)

```
Stream responseStream = CopyAndClose(resp.GetResponseStream());
// Do something with the stream
responseStream.Position = 0;
// Do something with the stream again


private static Stream CopyAndClose(Stream inputStream)
{
const int readSize = 256;
byte[] buffer = new byte[readSize];
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

int count = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, readSize);
while (count > 0)
{
    ms.Write(buffer, 0, count);
    count = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, readSize);
}
ms.Position = 0;
inputStream.Close();
return ms;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well you're asking it to *detect* the encoding... and that requires it to read data. That's reading it from the underlying stream, and you're then creating another `StreamReader` around the same stream.

I suggest you:

- Get the response stream
- Retrieve all the data into a byte array (or `MemoryStream`)
- Detect the encoding (which should be performed on *bytes*, not text - currently you're *already assuming UTF-8* by creating a `StreamReader`)
- Create a `MemoryStream` around the byte array, and a `StreamReader` around that

It's not clear what your `GetEncodingFromFirstLine` method does... or what this file really is. More information may make it easier to help you.

EDIT: If this is to load some XML, don't reinvent the wheel. Just give the stream to one of the existing XML-parsing classes, which will perform the appropriate detection for you.

Comment: @Skomski: Thanks - that makes it simpler, as the OP doesn't need to do the work at all.

Comment: Jon, thank you for your answer! I already tried detecting encoding on bytes, but it didn't work. I've updated the post with the GetEncodingFromFirstLine() method.

Comment: @Alex: You *must* detect the encoding based on the bytes, if you actually want to detect it at all. You will have lost information by creating a `StreamReader` around the bytes - because it will *impose* UTF-8 or UTF-16. However, see my edit - you don't need to do any of this at all. Just give the binary data to an XML parser.

Comment: you are right, I'm parsing XML. However when parsing xml files with Cyrillic characters I receive unreadable stuff, because those files use Windows cp1251 encoding. I need to detect the encoding and based on that encoding create the StreamReader.

Comment: @Alex: But the XML parser should be handling that for you, unless you're saying that the XML files are fundamentally *broken* to start with. The whole point of an XML file declaring its encoding is to allow the parser to hide all this from you.

Comment: That's interesting... When I parse the following XML file as is, I receive unreadable characters: http://feeds.feedburner.com/membrana_ru

Comment: @JonSkeet let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2268/discussion-between-alex-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: @Alex: No, I don't have time to devote to a 1-to-1 chat session. I'm doing lots of things at the same time - comments work much better for me.

Comment: @Alex: If that *HTML* is actually valid *XML*, it certainly doesn't use an XML declaration to specify the character encoding. It's got a charset within the `meta` tag, but that's quite different.

Comment: When I parse the following XML file as is, I receive unreadable characters: http://feeds.feedburner.com/membrana_ru
This is a screenshot of what I receive when I try to print the title of the first element to console: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14148878/…
And this is the correct title: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14148878/…
I specified the encoding when creating the stream reader: var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));

Comment: @Alex: I can't view either of those files. But does the web response not indicate the content type in the headers?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the current position in the stream to the beginning.

```
r.Position = 0;
string text = new StreamReader(r, Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding)).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: The stream comes from an HTTP response, so it's not seekable. And the OP wants to detect the encoding, whereas your code assumes the encoding is already known