# Data from stream is not written to file

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have a small import routine, which gets data from an ftp source, parses them and writes the data to a database with lint-to-sql. This is all working flawlessly, except the part, that the files which are being downloaded do not get saved locally.

The program follows these steps:

1. list all files on the source
2. iterate over all files
3. if file exists, skip
4. if file does not yet exist download and parse
5. parse content
6. save to db
7. **save to file (not working)**

The files get created in the appropriate folder but have a size of 0 bytes.
Where did I went wrong?

Code:

```
FtpWebResponse responseFileDownload = (FtpWebResponse)requestFileDownload.GetResponse();
try
{
    using (Stream responseStream = responseFileDownload.GetResponseStream())
    {
         using (FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(localPath + "\\downloads\\" + FtpListing[i], FileMode.Create))
         {
         //data which is not downloaded, already exists as a flatfile locally
         //write data from responsestream to db
             using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
             {
                 //ignore first line
                 string headline = reader.ReadLine();
                 #region Linq-To-Sql logic | Parsing
                 List<Messwert> fooList = new List<Messwert>();
                 //read rest of csv
                 using (var context = new DataContext())
                 {
                   //Logic edited out
                   //context.SubmitChanges();
                 }
             }
             #endregion
             responseStream.Position = 0;
             responseStream.CopyTo(writeStream);
         }
     }
 }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you stepped through the code? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn

Comment: Disposing the StreamReader will also close the underlying stream. i.e. the responsestream is closed before you reach the CopyTo statement.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the same problem: [How can I read an Http response stream twice in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147941/how-can-i-read-an-http-response-stream-twice-in-c)
You're trying to read the response stream twice.